# RegEx - Version in filename

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following schema for files that I want to parse with RegEx

```
[Custom/Random Name]_[MainVersion]_[MinorVersion].xls
```

Currently I have the following RegEx (which fails)

```
(?<firstPart>.+)_(?<mainVersion>\d+)(|_(?<minorVersion>\d+))\.xls
```

With this when the sample string is

```
Hello World_22_1.xls
```

it results in:

```
match.Groups["firstPart"].Value == "Hello World_22"
match.Groups["mainVersion"].Value == "1"
match.Groups["minorVersion"].Value == ""
```

but it should be

```
match.Groups["firstPart"].Value == "Hello World"
match.Groups["mainVersion"].Value == "22"
match.Groups["minorVersion"].Value == "1"
```

The problem is the my RegEx for the "firstPart" allows anycharacter with ".+" (which includes the "`_`") so it goes on till the last occurence of "`_`", there for I could rewrite my RegEx like this

```
(?<firstPart>[^_]+)_(?<mainVersion>\d+)(|_(?<minorVersion>\d+))\.xls
```

But this RegEx will than fail if the fileName is this:

```
Hello_World_22_1.xls
```

Resulting in:

```
match.Groups["firstPart"].Value == "World"
match.Groups["mainVersion"].Value == "22"
match.Groups["minorVersion"].Value == "1"
```

Is there a way to validate the string backwards, since the thing I am looking for is always at the end of the fileName?

The RegEx should return the correct value for those strings
(for simplicity I have written the desired result into the braces with [firstPart]/[mainVersion]/[minorVersion])

```
Hello World_22_1.xls (Hello World/22/1)
Hello_World_22_1.xls (Hello_World/22/1)
Hello_World_22.xls (Hello_World/22/)
Hello_1_World_22_1.xls (Hello_1_World/22/1)
Hello_1_World_22.xls (Hello_1_World/22/)
Hello_33_2_World_22_1.xls (Hello_33_2_World/22/1)
Hello_22_1_World.xls (//) --> (Wouldnt mind if the your solutions would return Hello_22_1_World as firstPart)
33_22.xls (33/22/)
33_22_1.xls (33/22/1)
```

Played around with reversing the inputed string but this "solution" is very questionable

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("Hello World_22_1.xls", "Hello World", "22", "1"));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("Hello_World_22_1.xls", "Hello_World", "22", "1"));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("Hello_World_22.xls", "Hello_World", "22", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("Hello_1_World_22_1.xls", "Hello_1_World", "22", "1"));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("Hello_1_World_22.xls", "Hello_1_World", "22", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("Hello_33_2_World_22_1.xls", "Hello_33_2_World", "22", "1"));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("Hello_22_1_World.xls", "", "", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("33_22.xls", "33", "22", ""));
    Console.WriteLine(TestRegEx("33_22_1.xls", "33", "22", "1"));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static bool TestRegEx(string str, string firstPart, string mainVersion, string minorVersion)
{
    var regEx = new Regex("slx\\.((?<minorVersion>\\d+)_|)(?<mainVersion>\\d+)_(?<firstPart>.+)");
    var reverseStr = new string(str.Reverse().ToArray());

    var match = regEx.Match(reverseStr);
    var x1 = new string(match.Groups["firstPart"].Value.Reverse().ToArray());
    var x2 = new string(match.Groups["mainVersion"].Value.Reverse().ToArray());
    var x3 = new string(match.Groups["minorVersion"].Value.Reverse().ToArray());

    return x1 == firstPart && x2 == mainVersion && x3 == minorVersion;
}
```

Comment: Try `(?<firstPart>.+?)_(?<mainVersion>\d+)(?:_(?<minorVersion>\d+))?\.xls`

Comment: Or `(?<firstPart>.+?)(?:_(?<mainVersion>\d+)(?:_(?<minorVersion>\d+))?)?\.xls`

Comment: The vertical line in your last digit group says "empty string OR ... digits", since the greedy first part can capture everything and then start backtracking, this last group is satisfied with "empty string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main trouble is certainly the greedy dot pattern at the beginning that grabs the whole input at first, and then backtracking only yields the last digits. To be able to use optional groups and get their contents if there are any, you need to use *lazy* quantifier with the dot matching pattern.

I suggest using

```
(?<firstPart>.+?)(?:_(?<mainVersion>\d+)(?:_(?<minorVersion>\d+))?)?\.xls
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3CfirstPart%3E.%2B%3F%29%28%3F%3A_%28%3F%3CmainVersion%3E%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F%3A_%28%3F%3CminorVersion%3E%5Cd%2B%29%29%3F%29%3F%5C.xls&i=Hello%20World_22_1.xls%20%28Hello%20World%2F22%2F1%29%0D%0AHello_World_22_1.xls%20%28Hello_World%2F22%2F1%29%0D%0AHello_World_22.xls%20%28Hello_World%2F22%2F%29%0D%0AHello_1_World_22_1.xls%20%28Hello_1_World%2F22%2F1%29%0D%0AHello_1_World_22.xls%20%28Hello_1_World%2F22%2F%29%0D%0AHello_33_2_World_22_1.xls%20%28Hello_33_2_World%2F22%2F1%29%0D%0AHello_22_1_World.xls%20%28%2F%2F%29%20--%3E%20%28Hello_22_1_World%20as%20firstPart%29%0D%0A33_22.xls%20%2833%2F22%2F%29%0D%0A33_22_1.xls%20%2833%2F22%2F1%29)

**Details**:

- `(?<firstPart>.+?)` - Group "firstPart" that matches any 0+ chars as few as possible due to the lazy `+?` quantifier
- `(?:_(?<mainVersion>\d+)(?:_(?<minorVersion>‌​\d+))?)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `_(?<mainVersion>\d+)`  - a `_` and the "mainVersion" group capturing 1 or more digits
  - `(?:_(?<minorVersion>‌​\d+))?` - an optional sequence of

    - `_` - an underscore
    - `(?<minorVersion>‌​\d+)` - a "minorVersion" group capturing 1+ digits
- `\.xls` - a `.xls` substring.

[image]

I'd prefer this to `(?<firstPart>.+?)_(?<mainVersion>\d+)(?:_(?<minorVersion>\d+‌​))?\.xls` regex because the latter won't match `Hello_22_1_World.xls` at all. If you do not need to match it, this last expression may be preferable.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about lazy quantifiers

Comment: See [*Laziness Instead of Greediness*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

Comment: Thx for your solution. Not sure if my computer or browser is going nuts right now, but when I try to copy and paste your solution (the top one) the string I have contains 2 invisible characters to be precise the char codes 8204 and 8203, is it just me? Could you maybe try to copy and paste your solution into visual studio and see it it works? `var strRegEx = "(?<firstPart>.+?)(?:_(?<mainVersion>\\d+)(?:_(?<minorVersion>‌​\\d+))?)?\\.xls";
if (strRegEx[60] == (char)8204) { }
if (strRegEx[61] == (char)8203) { }`

Comment: SO inserted some garbage into the code. I edited the answer.

Comment: Ah, okay. Was driving me crazy since I couldnt figure out why the f*** it wouldnt work on my side but your demo clearly showing that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^(?<firstPart>.+?)_(?<mainVersion>\d+)_(?<minorVersion>\d+)\.xls$
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/fa20nX/4)

Comment: Though the main idea of using lazy quantifier is good, OP wants to capture version from file name

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I edited my code to match the OP's need, Thanks for mentioning.